# Python Tkinter hide and show window via hotkeys

Tags: python, tkinter, hotkeys

I'm trying to write a program that I can hide and show via hotkeys. I managed to get the application to show and hide using the library "keyboard", however due to the "wait" function of the library, it prevents the Text box from functioning correctly. I have tried using the key bindings within Tkinter, however I had a different problem, whereby once the program was hidden or another application was selected, I couldn't return the focus to the hidden window via the hotkey.

```
import Tkinter as Tk
import keyboard

class MyApp(object):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.root = parent
        self.root.title("Main frame")

        self.frame = Tk.Frame(parent)
        self.frame.pack()

        self.editor = Tk.Text(self.frame)
        self.editor.pack()
        self.editor.config(font="Courier 12")
        self.editor.focus_set()


        keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+alt+s', self.show)
        keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+alt+h', self.hide)
        keyboard.wait()

        self.root.withdraw() 


    def show(self):
        self.root.update()
        self.root.deiconify()

    def hide(self):
        self.root.withdraw()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("800x600")
    app = MyApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Any assistance would be great :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just drop this wait command, its an additional mainloop, which is not needed as Tkinter does its job. I tried to fix your problem with threading, but as I wanted to check exactly what is NOT working, I accidentially made what I suppose you wanted to. So the Code is:

```
import tkinter as tk
import keyboard

class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("800x600")
        self.title("Main frame")

        self.editor = Tk.Text(self)
        self.editor.pack()
        self.editor.config(font="Courier 12")
        self.editor.focus_set()


        keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+alt+s', self.show)
        keyboard.add_hotkey('ctrl+alt+h', self.hide)


    def show(self):
        self.update()
        self.deiconify()

    def hide(self):
        self.update()
        self.withdraw()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().mainloop()
```

I hope this works for you. I'd also recommend changing this key settings. Testing with those in PyZo is IMPOSSIBLE! It always tries to "save as...", which I don't want to...

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid your code doesn't work for me. The hotkeys no longer work, and when used they appear to crash the application :(

Comment: Maybe. I Tried in python 3.5, there it worked fine. Which error do you get? Which Pythoversion? Obviously 2.x, but which one? I'll try doing it with threading then...

Comment: I'm using python 2.7. I got no error, just that the hotkeys dont appear to make the application show or hide and when I press them it places the application in a "not responding" state.

Comment: Don't worry! I upgraded to python 3.6 and your code appears to be working now :) thank you

Comment: nice :-) Should I keep trying with threading, as it is kind of a challenge, or is this solved?

Comment: I'm happy to accept your original answer as the solution. You've certainly fixed the problem for me.